# What do I have to do to display the largest and the smallest number using a loop?

Tags: java, loops

I don't  have  any idea how to display the largest and smallest number after the user enter -1.

Note:  I also have to display the sum of all of this number and the average of this sum.

Here's my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // store
    int cnt = 0;
    int acumulator = 0;
    int larger = 0;
    int smaller = 0;
    int number;
    // inputs
    System.out.println("enter the number all the number");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    number = kb.nextInt();
    // loop
    while (number != -1) {
        acumulator += number;
        number = kb.nextInt();
        cnt++;//
    }
    double average = (acumulator / cnt);
    System.out.println(" The total of your number is=" + acumulator);
    System.out.println(" The average of your number is=" + average);
}
```

Comment: Might I ask what the difference between `cnt` and `count` is and why only one is used? :-)

Comment: cnt is to know how  many  number have been entered,  count is an error.

Comment: I see that. But what is `count`? :-)

Comment: count  doesn't  do  anything. It is  my  mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like schoolwork, but what you could do is making a var and checking in your while if the input number is higher or lower then the saved var.

```
if(input > max)
  max = input;
```

And

```
if(input < min)
  min = input;
```

Comment: It looks like he already has them, but they're named `larger` and `smaller`; they're also unused.

Comment: Yeah i see, but its more about the idea :)

Comment: Thank  you  so  much. the homework  is  done,but can you explain the  logy of this situation or refer  me  to a wed-side where I can learn this better. My book  has a example but it doesn't explain this well and it is too short.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the following changes:

- use a for loop instead of a while loop (you need intialization, condition and iteration)
- use the JDK's API more - Math.min() and Math.max()
- spell "accumulator" correctly
- remove all variables you are not using (cnt)

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int accumulator = 0;
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int count = 0;
    // inputs
    System.out.println("enter a number (-1 to end)");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int number = kb.nextInt(); number != -1; number = kb.nextInt()) {
        count++;
        accumulator += number;
        largest = number > largest ? number : largest;
        smallest = number < smallest ? number : smallest;
    }
    double average = (accumulator / count);
    System.out.println(" The total of your numbers is=" + accumulator);
    System.out.println(" The average of your numbers is=" + average);
    System.out.println(" The largest of your numbers is=" + largest);
    System.out.println(" The smallest of your numbers is=" + smallest);
}
```

FYI: Math.min/max could be used instead of the ternary statements, but the above is the simplest java that will achieve the result.

Comment: the main problem  here is  that  my  teacher  has never taught how to  use Math.min() and Math.max(), and she may say  that it isn't what she wants.

Comment: Yeah its a good piece of code, but i guess for a beginner it might be confusing.

Comment: OK - I've removed the Math.min etc and replaced with ternaries

Comment: But ternaries are also confusing.  "if" statements would be the way to go for clear (but not so elegantly compact)  beginner code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to check each all numbers with each other.Lets say we have numbers 1,2 and 3

here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int one=1;
    int two=2;
    int three=3;
    if(three>one){
     if(three>two){
       System.out.println("three is biggest");
     }
   }
   if(two>one){
    if(two>three){

   }
}
```

etc etc.

I think you got idea

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an "if" statement.