# for loop: cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
    public class javapractice14
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter desired amount of numbers (-1 ends program)");
    for( int number = console.nextInt(); number != -1; number = console.nextInt()); //Enter -1 to end program
    {
```

I am receiving my error below saying it cannot find the symbol: variable number

I believe number was declared in the for loop, was it not declared there? I've tried declaring "**int number;**" outside the loop, but it ends with the same results. I used: [What do I have to do to display the largest and the smallest number using a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030979/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-display-the-largest-and-the-smallest-number-using-a-loop) as a reference for helping me solve part of this.

```
      largest = number > largest ? number : largest;
      smallest = number < smallest ? number : smallest;
    }
    System.out.println("Your largest number is: " + largest);
    System.out.println("You smallest number is: " + smallest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for( int number = console.nextInt(); number != -1; number = console.nextInt());` <--see there is a semicoln at end of your for loop it means loop end from there
so you can't refer to block variables declared inside the for loop from outside the loop. That is why you get that compile error

remove that semicoln. Then it must work fine

```
for( int number = console.nextInt(); number != -1; number = console.nextInt()){ // no semicol at the end
      // your logic
}
// print your numbers
```